# How to pass health check tests on AWS App Runner while deploying Python Bottle server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, devops, bottle, amazon-app-runner

I suppose this is a pretty dumb questions but I'm really poor at devops.

I have a small Python programming project which I need to deploy on the web. It's not a real app, just a small script which I need to put on the web for few days and then take it off.

I have developed a script which runs locally using Python `Bottle` server. Now, I'm running an AWS instance and I'm trying to deploy this app using `App Runner`. It seems as my environment and code is fine, but I can't pass the health checks. I only deployed code on traditional servers in the past, so I'm not familiar with the cloud operations.

```
11-05-2022 02:37:47 PM [AppRunner] Health check on port '8080' failed. Service is rolling back. Check your configured port number. For more information, read the application logs.
11-05-2022 02:31:36 PM [AppRunner] Performing health check on port '8080'.
11-05-2022 02:31:26 PM [AppRunner] Provisioning instances and deploying image for publicly accessible service.
11-05-2022 02:31:15 PM [AppRunner] Successfully built source code.
11-05-2022 02:26:53 PM [AppRunner] Starting source code build.
11-05-2022 02:26:52 PM [AppRunner] Successfully pulled source code.
11-05-2022 02:25:56 PM [AppRunner] Service status is set to OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS.
11-05-2022 02:25:55 PM [AppRunner] Service creation started.
```

This is the part of the code in my "server.py" file.

```
import os
from bottle import route, run, template, get, post, request
from scraper import scrap, get_dropdown_choices

index_html = '''My first web app! By <strong>{{ author }}</strong>.'''

@route('/')
def index():
    return template(index_html, author='Tim')

@route('/name/<name>')
def name(name):
    return template(index_html, author=name)

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

What should I do to pass the healtcheck tests?

Comment: Please provide more information about your App Runner setup, as it's otherwise only possible to guess what could be wrong.

Comment: We need more information, please. Does your app expose a `/` route? If not, that's going to cause the health check to fail. Either configure the health check to use an endpoint that your app does expose, or create a `/` endpoint. If neither of those is the problem, please edit your question and we'll take things from there. Thanks

Comment: @ronrothman I have added the route `/` endpoint as suggested. This route works fine locally.

Comment: Can you share the webserver logs with us? Did the server receive the health check call?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your server logs, I can only guess at the reason(s) for your failing health check. But one thing that jumps out at me is the `from scraper import scrap`, which seems like a typo.

And, indeed, when I try running the code your posted, I get this error:

```
    from scraper import scrapes, get_dropdown_choices
ImportError: cannot import name 'scrap' from 'scraper' (/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scraper/__init__.py)
```